# SSAS deployment failed > "File system error: Error opening file"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, deployment, ssas

For a few months we're developing an olap cube on SQL 2005. We deploy this cube on the local server which worked fine until a few weeks ago.
From that moment we got got an error while delpoying the cube.

"Error 1 File system error: Error opening file; \?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\OLAP\Data\SSAS_Funda.0.db\Dim Bron.0.dim.xml is not a disk file or file is not accessible.  0 0 "

The deployment proces should create these files, but that doesn't happen.

It looks like a permission problem. I check everything but couldn't find the problem. Either on Google I wasn't able to find the answer.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Aart

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem.
I decided to patch and update SQL server.
I updated SQL server 2005 to SP2 using SQLServer2005SP2-KB921896-x86-ENU.exe and after that I installed a batch of patches which are available in 344806_intl_i386_zip.exe.

Then I followed the following steps which resulted into a succesfull cube generation:
- unprocess all dimensions;
- full process all dimensions;
- unprocess the cube(s);
- process the structure of the cube(s);
- process default the cube(s).

Finally it worked. I think a previous Windows Server 2003 patch or SQL server patch caused security issues on certain users. Like the "Servicce Account" I use all the time.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this in the past, I have deleted the cube from the server and redeployed. This may not be an option in your situation. I would make a backup of the cube before trying this